# How much was it going to cost to pay Bombardier a premium to restart production of Mark I trains?

Tags: decision-theory

I read many web pages discussing the future plans of the [Scarborough RT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_3_Scarborough) and the cost of plans they were planning to do but not the cost of the premium they decided not to carry on with. Without knowing the cost of the premium, how can ordinary citizen help research whether paying a premium is a good solution?

Comment: This question could be improved by elaborating on what a "Scarborough RT" is, perhaps with links, mentioning where Scarborough is, and defining what a Mark I train is.

Comment: What's the actual economics concept that you're having difficulty with?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it stands, this isn't an economics question - it's just asking us to look up the price of something.